# Выступил или выступила?

Tags: сказуемые, род

> С информацией о состоянии
> семеноводства выступила заместитель
> руководителя по Нижегородской области
> Н.В. Ерастова.
>
> В работе семинара принимала участие
> директор по развитию И.Ю. Кузнецова.

Как правильно: *выступил* или *выступила*, *принимала* или *принимал*?

Вот если бы глаголы стояли после фамилии, то понятно, что их надо ставить в жен.р, но в этих случаях они находятся перед фамилией. Как быть?

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

*Как быть?*

Оставить так, как есть: *выступила, принимала.*

Answer (score 2):

Для меня обе фразы выглядят лучше с глаголом ж.р. В случае мужского рода в первой фразе сразу две проблемы:

1. Многословное указание должности настраивает читателя или слушателя на восприятие заместителя в мужском роде, но в конце он вынужден переосмыслить уже выслушанное. При этом впечатление такое, что личность выступившего не так важна, как его должность (если так нужно, то после должности в м.р. фамилию можно и в скобки поместить - это снимет грамматические проблемы).
2. Если читатель не знает, кто этот заместитель, то может понять, что речь идёт о неназванном заместиле г-на Ерастова.

Обе проблемы проще всего преодолеть, сначала назвав фамилию, затем уточнив должность.

С информацией о состоянии семеноводства выступила Н.В. Ерастова, заместитель руководителя по Нижегородской области.

Comment: Спасибо. Я так и исправила.